# Why can R's read.csv() read a CSV from GitLab URL when pandas' read_csv() can't?

Tags: python, r, pandas, read.csv

I noticed that panda's `read_csv()` fails at reading a public CSV file hosted on GitLab:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("https://gitlab.com/stragu/DSH/-/raw/master/Python/pandas/spi.csv")
```

The error I get (truncated):

```
HTTPError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-e1c0b52ee83c> in <module>
----> 1 df = pd.read_csv("https://gitlab.com/stragu/DSH/-/raw/master/Python/pandas/spi.csv")

[...]

~\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py in http_error_default(self, req, fp, code, msg, hdrs)
    647 class HTTPDefaultErrorHandler(BaseHandler):
    648     def http_error_default(self, req, fp, code, msg, hdrs):
--> 649         raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
    650 
    651 class HTTPRedirectHandler(BaseHandler):

HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
```

However, using R, the base function `read.csv()` reads it happily:

```r
df <- read.csv("https://gitlab.com/stragu/DSH/-/raw/master/Python/pandas/spi.csv")
head(df)
#>   country_code year   spi
#> 1          AFG 2020 42.29
#> 2          AFG 2019 42.34
#> 3          AFG 2018 40.61
#> 4          AFG 2017 38.94
#> 5          AFG 2016 39.65
#> 6          AFG 2015 38.62
```

<sup>Created on 2020-10-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Any idea why that is, and how R achieves it?

Versions used:

- R 4.0.3
- Python 3.7.9
- pandas 1.1.3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're looking for a workaround, I recommend making the GET request via [**`requests`**](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/) library:

```
import requests
from io import StringIO

url = "https://gitlab.com/stragu/DSH/-/raw/master/Python/pandas/spi.csv"
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(requests.get(url).text))
```

```
df.head()
  country_code  year        spi
0          AFG  2020  42.290001
1          AFG  2019  42.340000
2          AFG  2018  40.610001
3          AFG  2017  38.939999
4          AFG  2016  39.650002
```

---

As to the "why" part of it, I see [`read_csv` internally uses `urllib` for standard URLs](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/10e5ad7109f1bb3c47b48b6f0df185e108c5493d/pandas/io/common.py#L254-L259), apparently the API in question blocks the request possibly because it thinks you are a crawler. If I repeat the same process, but add The "User-Agent" header, the request succeeds.

TLDR; what pandas does and fails:

```
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen

req = Request(<URL>)
urlopen(req).read() # fails
```

What pandas should have done for this to work:

```
req = Request(<URL>)
req.add_header('User-Agent', <literally anything>)
urlopen(req).read() # succeeds
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. Do you have any insights on how R's `read.csv()` does that differently for it to work without having to do anything extra? That would make a perfect answer. I suspect it has to do with how `base::url()` works. For example, `url("https://gitlab.com/stragu/DSH/-/raw/master/Python/pandas/spi.csv")` returns a valid connection that can be fed to `read.csv()` without a problem.

Comment: Unfortunately I have 0 knowledge of R so your guess is as good (or possibly better) than mine.